# Where does Rails.logger.debug go when called from cron task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, amazon-web-services, cron, rake

I have a Rails application running inside a Docker container named `bubbles`. There are various places in my app which write to Rails.logger.debug. Our devops guy has hooked up the container to Cloudwatch, where our debug logs are viewable.

Every five minutes, as my server `root`, I call a `Rake` task in that application via the following `cron` task:

`0/5 * * * * root   docker exec -ti bubbles bundle exec rake chocolate:skittles`

The method in the Rake task writes to `Rails.logger.debug`. I expected to be able to view these debug files in Cloudwatch.

However, nothing shows up in the logs for the task, whether it is called from `cron` or `bash`.

What am I missing here?